# Client certificate authentication in web service

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-runtime

We are working on an Windows Runtime and Windows Phone 8 application which connects to a server via web services.

I am wondering how I can add client authentication with certificates to the web service call, as ClientCertificate is not available on ClientCredentials for Windows Runtime/Windows Phone 8. See API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.clientcredentials.clientcertificate.aspx

Can anyone point me in the right direction how to add a client certificate to the call to our generated web service.

Regards Matoz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Windows Phone 8 sdk does not support client certificate. Please see [MSDN LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402533#BKMK_SecureSocketsLayerSSLcertificates) for more details.